# Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x^2(x^2+1)y''-2x^3y'+2(x^2-1)y=0$$

Anyway my tutor assumes that one of the solutions must be $y=x^2$, yet I can't seem to prove this, I tried using $y=x^n$ but I can't seem to get an answer that cancels down. I know soon as I get this solution I can use Abel's forumla to get the other solution.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: see here to learn to use Latex http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You said you cant type LaTeX but in this case, it was simply putting `$` or `$$` around your math, that can't be too hard.

Comment: @Amzoti Say I didn't know the solution was $$y=x^2$$ How would I find this? Is it just a logical guess?

Comment: $x=0$ is a regular singular point, with indicial equation $(r+1)(r-2)=0$, so you can look for series solutions of the form $\sum_{n=-1}^\infty a_n x^n$ or $\sum_{n=-2}^\infty a_n x^n$.  The recursion for the coefficients turns out to be $(n-4)(n-3) a_{n-2} +(n-2)(n+1) a_n = 0$.  From this you get the two solutions $y = 1/x + 3 x$ and $y = x^2$ (the factors $n-4$ and $n-3$ make the coefficients of $x^3$, $x^4$ zero, and then anything higher is also zero).

Answer (score 1):

If $y=x^{2}$ then

$y' = 2x$

$y'' = 2$

Simply insert it into the equation and check that it is satisfied:

$x^2(x^2+1)2-(2x^3)2x+2(x^2-1)x^2=2x^4+2x^2-4x^4+2x^4-2x^2=0$

Answer (score 0):

Let $r=x^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{dr}\dfrac{dr}{dx}=2x\dfrac{dy}{dr}$

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(2x\dfrac{dy}{dr}\right)=2x\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dr}\right)+2\dfrac{dy}{dr}=2x\dfrac{d}{dr}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dr}\right)\dfrac{dr}{dx}+2\dfrac{dy}{dr}=2x\dfrac{d^2y}{dr^2}2x+2\dfrac{dy}{dr}=4x^2\dfrac{d^2y}{dr^2}+2\dfrac{dy}{dr}=4r\dfrac{d^2y}{dr^2}+2\dfrac{dy}{dr}$

$\therefore r(r+1)\left(4r\dfrac{d^2y}{dr^2}+2\dfrac{dy}{dr}\right)-4r^2\dfrac{dy}{dr}+2(r-1)y=0$

$4r^2(r+1)\dfrac{d^2y}{dr^2}+2r(r+1)\dfrac{dy}{dr}-4r^2\dfrac{dy}{dr}+2(r-1)y=0$

$4r^2(r+1)\dfrac{d^2y}{dr^2}-2r(r-1)\dfrac{dy}{dr}+2(r-1)y=0$

$\because$ The latter ODE has trivial solution $y=r$

$\therefore$ The former ODE has trivial solution $y=x^2$